# Override to_representation in List serializer class

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

I have a serializer that implements the `BaseSerializer` class in which I'm using the `to_representation` function to do a function call like so:

```
class ItemSerializer(serializers.BaseSerializer):
    def to_representation(self, instance):
        ret = super().to_representation(instance)
        ret['log'] = SERVICE.log(instance.id)
        return ret

    class Meta:
        list_serializer_class = ItemListSerializer
        model = models.Item
        fields = '__all__'
```

I also have a list serializer for the same `ItemListSerializer` which looks like this:

```
class ItemListSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):
    def create(self, validated_data):
        items = [models.Item(**item) for item in validated_data]
        return models.Item.objects.bulk_create(items)
```

What I want to do is override the `to_representation` method in the `ItemSerializer` for when I want to get the entire list of Items. I basically want to avoid doing a function call per item and instead do a bulk call for all the items when the list of items is requested for performance reasons.

Is there a good way to do this? I followed these docs for creating the `ItemListSerializer`:https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#customizing-listserializer-behavior but it only talks about overriding create and update methods.

Comment: List serializer has its own implementation of `to_representation`. Check it https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/1c3f796219e7794306bb2db81d4910c0cb7c932a/rest_framework/serializers.py#L674

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can access all items in [`ListSerializer.to_representation`](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/1c3f796219e7794306bb2db81d4910c0cb7c932a/rest_framework/serializers.py#L674)

It should be a good place to do what you want.

The method looks like this:

```
def to_representation(self, data):
    """
    List of object instances -> List of dicts of primitive datatypes.
    """
    # Dealing with nested relationships, data can be a Manager,
    # so, first get a queryset from the Manager if needed
    iterable = data.all() if isinstance(data, models.Manager) else data

    return [
        self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable
    ]
```

But to be honest I don't see what would you gain from it. Your use case looks like it will be no measurable performance boost.

Comment: Its because I'm making a HTTP call for each item in the list and I'd like to avoid doing that and use a single call and get all the data. Then I can assign the data appropriately in the `to_representation`. Its a very niche case but the performance improved by a lot once I implemented this :)

Comment: @VishalRao It makes perfect sense if your SERVICE.log is time-consuming (HTTP, database query) and you want it repeated in all your objects.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to avoid duplicating the code of `ListSerializer.to_representation()`, you may use a patched version of it like `patched_to_representation_v1()` in https://github.com/LLyaudet/django-monkey-patches, https://github.com/LLyaudet/django-monkey-patches/blob/16d59ca9bbb55451cef7a6097b24bd6ba9e44869/src/django_monkey_patches/django_rest_framework__list_serializer__to_representation.py#L41.
You may apply the patch to `ListSerializer`, or for better performances, you can use it in custom classes inheriting of `ListSerializer`.